# What would set S = N \ {P} mean in pseudocode?

Tags: pseudocode

Learning about DBscan from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBSCAN). The article has the following pseudocode:

```
DBSCAN(DB, distFunc, eps, minPts) {
   C = 0                                                  /* Cluster counter */
   for each point P in database DB {
      if label(P) ≠ undefined then continue               /* Previously processed in inner loop */
      Neighbors N = RangeQuery(DB, distFunc, P, eps)      /* Find neighbors */
      if |N| < minPts then {                              /* Density check */
         label(P) = Noise                                 /* Label as Noise */
         continue
      }
      C = C + 1                                           /* next cluster label */
      label(P) = C                                        /* Label initial point */
      Seed set S = N \ {P}                                /* Neighbors to expand */
      for each point Q in S {                             /* Process every seed point */
         if label(Q) = Noise then label(Q) = C            /* Change Noise to border point */
         if label(Q) ≠ undefined then continue            /* Previously processed */
         label(Q) = C                                     /* Label neighbor */
         Neighbors N = RangeQuery(DB, distFunc, Q, eps)   /* Find neighbors */
         if |N| ≥ minPts then {                           /* Density check */
            S = S ∪ N                                     /* Add new neighbors to seed set */
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I am pretty sure that |N| would mean the count of N.

What would the line:

```
      Seed set S = N \ {P}                                /* Neighbors to expand */
```

mean? I *think* that S is a seed set like a list of objects. What does the N \ {P} mean?

Comment: in set theory, \ usually means difference (those belong to N and not to {P})

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\` is the complement operation, therefore `N \ {P}` is the set of neighbours `N` without point `P`. Meaning all points surrounding `P` with a certain distance, returned by `RangeQuery(DB, distFunc, P, eps)` (the query result  includes `P`).

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_(set_theory)